# Combine multiple statements into an expression in Perl?

Tags: perl, activeperl

Is it possible to combine multiple statements into a single expression? A block could do this but I am wondering whether they could also be packaged into a expression.

Comment: A subroutine will combine expressions into a single. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's what `do { ... }` is for.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem - what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly [`do BLOCK`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)'s purpose.

For example,

```
my $file = do {
   open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die $!;
   local $/;
   <$fh>
};
```